# Is there an open-source option to convert CityGML and an ADE to tilesets?

Tags: gis, cesiumjs, ogc

I'm using data generated by the KIT (FZK Haus) to visualize it in CesiumJS and want to  display the the different attributes of the CityGML object and the EnergyADE.

With the library "citygml-to-3dtiles" I loose all attributes that are included in the ADE.

Is there any open option to change that?

I've tried FME Software, however my license expired. With the open alternative py3dtiles I also use the information in the ADE.